# The accuracy of PHP float calculate

Tags: php

```
$fooValue = 100.68;
$cowValue = 100.67;

$diffValue = $fooValue - $cowValue;
if($diffValue <= 0.01) {
    echo("success");
} else {
    echo("error");
}
```

This will show "error".

I know what to do in Java. But I'm not good at PHP, especially with this calculate things.

Please help me out. I mean how to succeed this?

Comment: Remember [`abs()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.abs.php) if you're not confident that `$fooValue` is always the greatest of the two. Your problem, however, seems to be that your epsilon is too small, thus giving a wrong result due to float value representation.

Comment: `$diffValue` equals to `0.010000000000005` due to the floating point representation; that's not special to php.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Float is an inexact datatype (as all floating-point datatypes are), because you may lose precision when converting to and from binary. This is why you shouldn't use floating-point arithmetic when you need high (exact) precision.

In PHP, check out [BC Math](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) or the [GMP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php) library. The latter will only work with integers, but it has high performance and sometimes it's possible to convert to and from integers without losing precision.

Comment: Instead of thank you if you got the result accept the answer and give up vote to him.