# pow function in a C for-loop rounding down

Tags: c

I'm trying out the pow-function in c, and something goes wrong.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int highnumber = 18; 
    int input = 344;
    int diff[18];
    for(int j = 1; j<=highnumber; j++){
       diff[j-1] = input - pow(j,2);
       printf("%d\n",diff[j-1]);
    }
}
```

I get the output:

```
343
340
335
328
319
308
295
280
263
244
223
200
175
147
119
88
54
19
```

Now the last two entries, doesn't make sense to me. They should be 55 and 20. Anyone knows why this happens?

Okay, I change the indexing, and show that pow function works:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int highnumber = 18; 
    int input = 344;
    int diff[18];
    for(int j = 0; j<=highnumber; j++){
       diff[j] = input - pow(j,2);
       printf("%d\n",diff[j]);
    }
    int a = input - pow(17,2);
    int b = input - pow(18,2);
    printf("%d\n%d",a,b);
}
```

Output:

344
343
340
335
328
319
308
295
280
263
244
223
200
175
147
119
88
54
19
55
20

Comment: Although the indexing is a bit weird (`j = 0; j < highnumber; j++){ diff[j] ..` is more idiomatic), it isn't wrong or UB. This is not a duplicate of the other question

Comment: It is working fine for me.

Comment: @Kninnug is right, this is not a duplicate. The indexing is pretty fine.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. pow(17,2) is defined, and if I put it outside the for loop, this gives the correct result. I can also change the starting integer from 0 instead of 1, so I get 344 with from the beginning. it doesn't change the fact that the two last integers are wrong.

Comment: More than likely, there is a typo in your original code that wasn't copied here or there's a bug in your compiler.

Comment: This is the exact copy, and I also tried to run the code in cmd, still same result.

Comment: It looks like, when we go above 16^2 = 256 , it crashes..

Comment: Please post your actual code. The code you have provided doesn't exhibit the behavior you describe, but the behavior you expect.

Comment: no this is the exact code I compile and execute. And the output is exact copy of the output I'm given.

Comment: Then please give details on which compiler and which OS you use and how you build and run it. Here you can see it works: http://ideone.com/UGw6r0

Comment: [https://ideone.com/sixwi9](https://ideone.com/sixwi9)

Comment: It's a well-known problem that `pow(a, b)` doesn't always give you the result you expect when `b` is a small integer like 2 or 3.  This is because `pow` may use logarithms instead of straight multiplications. It's likely that in this case, the compiler is doing a compile-time optimization when `a` is constant (that is, in the last two lines the OP added), and that the compile-time optimization gets a slightly different answer than the run-time `pow` call.

Comment: @SteveSummit can you provide a reference for this?

Comment: @moooeeeep See the footnote at http://c-faq.com/fp/pow.html .

Comment: So I'm using something called git-bash.

Comment: i use gcc to compile and my OS is windows 7

Comment: okay the compiler is mingw64

Comment: I fixed it using (int) pow(i,2)

Comment: @12344343243 I'm surprised that casting to `(int)` helped.  In general the problem with calling `pow()` to square things is that it sometimes returns an answer that's a tiny bit too small.  But since conversion from double to int *truncates* (that is, since it does *not* round), you sometimes get a result that's too small by 1.

Comment: @moooeeeep and 12344343243: see these other questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18155883/ , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16923249/ .

Comment: @12344343243 To see what's going on, try running `for(int j = 0; j<=highnumber; j++) printf("%d  %.20f\n", j, pow(j, 2));`.

Comment: You're right all. it's the integer input to pow that's the problem. (int) infront fixes the last two entries, but then messes up some of the others. As I only needed a square function, I just created this one. How to solve this problem in general, I don't know.

Comment: @SteveSummit Nice - thanks for these resources! These questions you've linked seem to better fit for this being a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [return value of pow() gets rounded down if assigned to an integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7937286/return-value-of-pow-gets-rounded-down-if-assigned-to-an-integer)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unusual output from pow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16923249/unusual-output-from-pow)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strange behaviour of the pow function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18155883/strange-behaviour-of-the-pow-function)