# Allocating dynamic array within a function of a structure

Tags: c, arrays, memory, struct

I have a BST structure:

```
struct bst {
    int *data;
    int max;
};
```

And I have a function to create a bst initially:

```
struct bst *create_bst(int max) {
    struct bst *b;
    b->data = malloc(pow(2, max) * sizeof(int));

    return b;
}
```

But I'm getting error at the line where I'm allocating memory to data.
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You getting an error because you have not allocated memory for `b` since you defined it as a pointer to a `struct bst`

Comment: What is the value of max when the malloc fails?

Comment: `struct bst *b;` --> `struct bst *b = malloc(sizeof(*b));`

Comment: @T.V. Do I just add b = malloc(sizeof(struct bst)); ?

Comment: Note: An alternative `pow(2, max)` here is `(size_t)1 << max)`.

Comment: @WernerHenze I tried with max = 4, but it failed.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY After adding that line, it still fails at malloc of a->data saying there were memory leaks :/

Comment: Suggest `struct bst *b = malloc(sizeof *b); b->data = malloc( ((size_t)1 << max) * sizeof *(b->data)); b->max = max;`

Comment: @Haxify `a->data` ?? It does not take this case memory leak here(`b->data = ...`).

Comment: @chux `malloc(sizeof *b)` is not allocating the correct amount of memory, it's only allocating the size of a pointer.
@Haxify please refer to @Dogbert's answer, his solution should work and handle's error if allocation fails.

Comment: @T.V. you misunderstand `*b`. `*b` is not pointer.

Comment: @T.V.  `malloc(sizeof *b)` _is_ the correct amount of memory.  `sizeof of *b` is the size of the structure pointed to by `b`.  Try compiling it.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY You're right, my mistake. Haven't written C code in a long time.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I meant b->data, sorry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not allocating data for the `struct` itself, just one of its members. This should help:

```
struct bst *create_bst(int max) {
    struct bst *b;
    if ((b = calloc((size_t)1, sizeof(struct bst))) == NULL) {
        printf("Allocation error\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    if ((b->data = calloc((size_t)1<<max, sizeof(int))) == NULL) {
        printf("Allocation error\n");
        free(b);
        return NULL;
    }

    return b;
}
```

Later on in some other part of your code, you'll need to clean this memory up. ie: `free(b->data); free(b)`.

Also, [remember that `pow` doesn't work quite how you think it does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7937286/return-value-of-pow-gets-rounded-down-if-assigned-to-an-integer). You could get something like `pow(5,2) == 24.999999...`, and when you assign this value to an integer variable, it gets truncated to `24`. Never mix and match `int` and `float` logic unless you know exactly what you're doing.