# Clang possibly skipping line(s) of code while compiling

Tags: c, recursion, return, clang

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define MAX_BITS 32

int counter = 0, dec_eqv = 0;
int runcounter = 1;

int binToDec(char *bit)
{
    printf("dec_eqv is %d\n", dec_eqv);
    if (counter == 0 && runcounter)
    {
        dec_eqv = 0;
        int i = 0;
        while (*(bit + i++))
            ;
        counter = (i - 1) - 1;
        runcounter = 0;
        printf("counter is %d\n", counter);
    }
    if (*bit != 0)
    {
        printf("*bit not zero\n");
        if (*bit == '1')
        {
            dec_eqv += (int)pow(2, counter--);
        }
        else
        {
            counter--;
        }
        binToDec(bit + 1);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("here *bit is 0\n");
        runcounter = 1;
        printf ("here dec_eqv is %d\n", dec_eqv);
        return dec_eqv;
        printf ("Skipping return\n");
    }
    return -1;
}

int main()
{
    char bin[MAX_BITS];
    printf("Enter binary number (%d-bit max): ", MAX_BITS);
    scanf("%[^\n]s", bin);
    int result = binToDec(bin);
    printf("Decimal equivalent of 0b%s is %d.", bin, result);
    return 0;
}
```

I've added the `printf()` statements in `binToDec()` for debugging, and it seems that the compiler is ignoring the `return dec_eqv;` statement in the final `else` block and directly executing the `return -1;` at the end. What could be possibly wrong? I am using Clang/LLVM compiler in Ubuntu 23.10 AMD64 and no errors or warnings were generated during compilation.

Comment: If `*bit != 0`, you make a recursive call to `binToDec()` but its value is not returned – the code “falls through”. The last call in the recursive chain always returns -1. Try `return binToDec(bit + 1);` if `*bit != 0`.

Comment: @PaulLynch ```*bit``` becomes 0 always because character arrays terminate with ```'\0'``` which is equal to 0. So the ```else``` block must execute when traversal through the character array ```bin``` is complete. If the ```else``` block executes then ```return dec_eqv;``` must execute, which is not happening and the function returns -1 in all cases. The ```return dec_eqv;``` is ignored by the compiler.

Comment: Yes, the `else` block is executed at the end of the string. However, this is only upon the last recursive call to `binToDec()`. In all the prior calls `*bit != 0`, but since there is no return in this block -1 will always be returned at the end of the function. Again, try `return binToDec(bit + 1);` if `*bit != 0`.

Comment: This too:  `dec_eqv += (int)pow(2, counter--)`?  [Don't use `pow()` for *integer* calculations.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7937286/return-value-of-pow-gets-rounded-down-if-assigned-to-an-integer)

Comment: @AndrewHenle Thank you for your suggestion. I'll update my code to account for it.

Comment: @ArijitKD The lesson here is don’t blame the compiler :) `return dec_eqv;` was not “being ignored” by the compiler, it was ignored in your implementation.