# Why pow(10,5) = 9,999 in C++

Tags: c++, mingw, pow

Recently i write a block of code:

```
const int sections = 10;

for(int t= 0; t < 5; t++){
   int i = pow(sections, 5- t -1);  
   cout << i << endl;
}
```

And the result is wrong:

```
9999
1000
99
10
1
```

If i using just this code:

```
for(int t = 0; t < 5; t++){
    cout << pow(sections,5-t-1) << endl; 
}
```

The problem doesn't occur anymore:

```
10000
1000
100
10
1
```

Does anyone give me an explaination? thanks you very much!

Comment: What type is `sections`, and how is it initialised?

Answer (score 11):

Due to the representation of floating point values `pow(10.0, 5)` could be 9999.9999999 or something like this. When you assign that to an integer that got truncated.

EDIT: In case of `cout << pow(10.0, 5);` it looks like the output is rounded, but I don't have any supporting document right now confirming that.

EDIT 2: The comment made by BoBTFish and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554063/how-do-i-print-a-double-value-with-full-precision-using-cout) confirms that when `pow(10.0, 5)` is used directly in `cout` that is getting rounded.

Comment: This doesn't explain why printing directly doesn't print 9999.9999999

Comment: @Luchian Grigore, is it possible that in that case it is getting rounded? I would like to hear that explanation too.

Comment: If the default precision is less the number of decimal places it would be rounded.

Comment: @BoBTFish, can you explain a little more. Is that the behavior of `cout`?

Comment: Is there any solution to get `int i = pow(10,5) = 10,000`?

Comment: @Kingfisher, on my machine `int i = pow(10, 5)` results 10000, but pow(10.0, 5) does not. Looks like `sections` is double in your code. If you really need `sections` to be double then instead of assign it to `i` you need to round the power.

Comment: `std::cout` will round floats to a specified number of significant figures, which can be changed using the `std::setprecision` manipulator. So if you try to output `99.9999` (which remember is actually the closest approximation to that it can manage, not the exact number) with a precision of say 4, the rounding will "carry the 1" all the way up and print 100.

Comment: @taskinoor Which compiler/library are you using that can't accurately compute `pow(10.0, 5);`?

Comment: @Mark B, I'm using gcc 4.4.1 with MinGW32 on a windows 7 machine.

Answer (score 3):

When used with fractional exponents, pow(x,y) is commonly evaluated as `exp(log(x)*y)`; such a formula would mathematically correct if evaluated with infinite precision, but may in practice result in rounding errors.  As others have noted, a value of 9999.999999999 when cast to an integer will yield 9999.  Some languages and libraries use such a formulation all the time when using an exponentiation operator with a floating-point exponent; others try to identify when the exponent is an integer and use iterated multiplication when appropriate.  Looking up documentation for the `pow` function, it appears that it's supposed to work when `x` is negative and `y` has no fractional part (when `x` is negative and `` `y `` is even, the result should be `pow(-x,y)`; when `y` is odd, the result should be `-pow(-x,y)`.  It would seem logical that when `y` has no fractional part a library which is going to go through the trouble of dealing with a negative `x` value should use iterated multiplication, but I don't know of any spec dictating that it must.

In any case, if you are trying to raise an integer to a power, it is almost certainly best to use integer maths for the computation or, if the integer to be raised is a constant or will always be small, simply use a lookup table (raising numbers from 0 to 15 by any power that would fit in a 64-bit integer would require only a 4,096-item table).

Answer (score 2):

From [Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20161117034150/http://aleeee.com/fpu_sse.html)

Looking at the `pow()` function: `double pow (double base, double exponent);` we know the parameters and return value are all `double` type. But the variable `num`, `i` and `res` are all `int` type in code above, when tranforming `int` to `double` or `double` to `int`, it may cause precision loss. For example (maybe not rigorous), the floating point unit (FPU) calculate `pow(10, 4)=9999.99999999`, then `int(9999.9999999)=9999` by type transform in C++.

### How to solve it?

#### Solution1

Change the code:

```
    const int num = 10;

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
       double res = pow(num, i);
       cout << res << endl;
    }
```

#### Solution2

Replace floating point unit (FPU) having higher calculation precision in `double` type. For example, we use SSE in Windows CPU. In Code::Block 13.12, we can do this steps to reach the goal: Setting -> Compiler setting -> GNU GCC Compile -> Other options, add

`-mfpmath=sse -msse3`

The picture is as follows:

[image: add <code>-mfpmath=sse -msse3</code>]
<sub>(source: [qiniudn.com](http://aleeee.qiniudn.com/change%20SSE%20in%20CB.png))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Whats happens is the pow function returns a double so 
when you do this

```
int i = pow(sections, 5- t -1);
```

the decimal .99999 cuts of and you get 9999.

while printing directly or comparing it with 10000 is not a problem because it is runded of in a sense.

Answer (score 1):

If the code in your first example is the exact code you're running, then you have a buggy library. Regardless of whether you're picking up `std::pow` or C's `pow` which takes doubles, even if the double version is chosen, 10 is exactly representable as a `double`. As such the exponentiation is exactly representable as a `double`. No rounding or truncation or anything like that should occur.

With g++ 4.5 I couldn't reproduce your (strange) behavior even using `-ffast-math` and `-O3`.

Now what I suspect is happening is that `sections` is *not* being assigned the literal 10 directly but instead is being read or computed internally such that its value is something like `9.9999999999999`, which when raised to the fourth power generates a number like `9999.9999999`. This is then truncated to the integer 9999 which is displayed.

Depending on your needs you may want to round either the source number or the final number prior to assignment into an int. For example: `int i = pow(sections, 5- t -1) + 0.5; // Add 0.5 and truncate to round to nearest.`

Answer (score 0):

There must be some broken `pow` function in the global namespace. Then `std::pow` is "automatically" used instead in your second example because of ADL.

Either that or `t` is actually a floating-point quantity in your first example, and you're running into rounding errors.

Comment: Is it not a rounding issue like I originally thought?

Comment: No, this was gcc bug. Libm of glibc is not even used here.

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning the result to an int.  That coerces it, truncating the number.

This should work fine:

```
for(int t= 0; t < 5; t++){
   double i = pow(sections, 5- t -1);  
   cout << i << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simple solution you can try is..
just add 0.1 in your code.

const int sections = 10;

```
for(int t= 0; t < 5; t++){
   int i = pow(sections, 5- t -1)+0.1;  
   cout << i << endl;
}
```

Comment: The question doesnt want to round the result. He/she is asking about why in C++ this result happen.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers about doubles rounding to 9999.99999 internally, it's also important to note that by default, streams have a precision of 6, and which means they round in teh output at 6 digits. So when you print the double directly, it rounds correctly to 10000. But if you cast it to an `int` first, that truncates to 9999.
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/precision

Answer (score -1):

What happens is that your answer is actually 99.9999 and not exactly 100. This is because `pow` is double. So, you can fix this by using `i = ceil(pow())`.

Your code should be:

```
const int sections = 10;
for(int t= 0; t < 5; t++){
   int i = ceil(pow(sections, 5- t -1));  
   cout << i << endl;
}
```

Comment: You cannot use `ceil(pow())` because it *too* can be off.

Comment: No, it is just a bug.