# Binary to decimal converter in c logic error

Tags: c, loops

I was trying to make a binary to decimal converter in c. But the out put that now comes is a random number. Before I that tried, it used to work for binary which consists of all 1s. eg when I enter 111 it used to give me 7. But when I entered 10 or 011 or anything else it gives me some random number. Now it gives me like it's a memory location. Please help. I tried with a online compiler.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include<math.h>

 int main() {

int i=1, b[100];
char ch;
int decimal=0;
printf("enter binary\n");
ch=getchar();
while(ch!='\n'){
    ch=ch-'0';
    b[i]=ch;
    i++;
    ch=getchar();
}
i=i-1;
while(i>=0){
    decimal=(b[i]*((int)pow(2,i))) + decimal;
    i--;
}
printf("%d",(int)decimal);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `i=1` How about the 0 index? The current code reads but does not set `b[0]`.

Comment: Note that [`getchar`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) returns an **`int`**, which is rather important if you want to compare the result to the `int` value `EOF` (which you really should do).

Comment: Also don't use the floating-point `pow` function for dealing with powers of two, use bit-shifting instead.

Comment: Oh, and are you really learning C++? There's nothing specific to C++ in the code you show, it could all be plain C. If you're programming in C, then why did you add the C++ tag? Proper tagging is important to get the right people to see your questions.

Comment: Lastly a couple of points about `printf("%d",(int)decimal);` That makes the program invalid and not a proper [mre]. A proper [mre] should replicate the problem you ask about and *only* the problem you ask about. Always make sure to build and test your [mre] before copy-pasting it into your question. The second note is that the `%d` format expects an `int` argument, the variable `decimal` is an `int`, so the cast isn't needed. Why did you add the cast?

Answer (score 1):

As comments pointed out probably initializing i as 0 would reduce complexity of working with i as index. Therefore there won't be a free b[0] in array.
It would also help to produce powers of 2 by a for loop , most of the times using pow function may lead to some unwanted casting behavior especially when double type output is not wanted.

Try this method of summation :

```
for (int j=0 ; j<i ; j++){
    decimal *=2 ;
    decimal += b[j] ;
}
```

Also for getting binary number it would work out to ask user the length of number and then using scanf("%s",b) to avoid character by character input.

Answer (score 0):

The comments above suggest initializing `i` to `0` instead of `1`. You definitely need to do that.

But you can also avoid the historical inaccuracies of the `pow` function by not using it and iterating over your array in the other direction. It enables you to stay in the integer space and avoid having to cast.
Details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13774912/gcc-c-pow-accuracy).

Instead of this:

```
while(i>=0){
    decimal=(b[i]*((int)pow(2,i))) + decimal;
    i--;
}
```

This:

```
for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    decimal = decimal * 2 + b[j];
}
```