# Sensitive operations with big numbers in C++

Tags: c++, numbers

I want to make a program that takes a number input from the user and tells whether the number is a square of an integer or not. My code runs correctly when inputs are small numbers. But when I enter really big numbers like 2^60+100, it says number is a square of an integer, but in fact it is not. (it works fine when it takes 2^60, it says number is a square of an integer. it also works fine when it takes 2^61, it says number is not a square of an integer) By the way, I am using `long long` datatype to store big numbers. A portion of my code is like this:

```cpp
long long num = pow(2, 60);
if (pow(floor(sqrt(num)), 2) == num) {
    cout << "a"; // true
}
else {
    cout << "b";
}
```

```cpp
long long num = pow(2, 60)+100;
if (pow(floor(sqrt(num)), 2) == num) {
    cout << "a"; // wrong
}
else {
    cout << "b";
}
```

```cpp
long long num = pow(2, 61);
if (pow(floor(sqrt(num)), 2) == num) {
    cout << "a";
}
else {
    cout << "b"; // correct
}
```

My code should be so sensitive that can distinguish the difference between 2^60 and 2^60+1

The solution for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13774912/gcc-c-pow-accuracy) does not work in my situation. Solutions second parameter is a constant meanwhile in my code, it is not constant and the code still runs incorrectly.

Comment: FYI, `pow(2,x)` can be more efficiently expressed as `(1 << x)`, provided your data type can support at least `x` bits.  The latter expression can usually be expressed with 1 or 2 assembly instructions.

Comment: The `pow()` function is *floating point*.  You may get some numerical errors when converting from integral to floating point and back.   See [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating Point](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: A 64-bit integer can accurately represent 2^60+1, because there are at least 60 bits.  However a 64-bit floating point (a.k.a. `double`) cannot because the `double` has to reserve bits for mantissa and exponent.

Comment: `sqrt` and `floor` are also floating point.

Comment: So, what should I do to make this code work, solution for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13774912/gcc-c-pow-accuracy) does not work for me

Comment: Use a *Big Number* library.  There are a plethora of the them.  You want a floating point representation with the biggest mantissa you can find.

Comment: Read the article I linked to.  Not all numbers can be represented by computer floating point.  Without computers, some numbers still can't be "sensitive", such as 1.0/3.0.  With floating point, the question isn't a yes or no, but to what degree is the sensitivity or accuracy.  Read up on Scientific Notation.  For example, when are two floating points numbers equal?  Are they equal at 1E-5 or 1E-9?  Think:  **How much sensitivity do you require?**

Comment: I need maximum sensitivity as code is all about that, thank you for help

Comment: The limit to your sensitivity is the hardware components or sensors.  At my shop we use an Analog to Digital Converter (ADC).  Standard ADC has 12 bits of sensitivity.  More expensive ADCs have 16 bits.  A Compact Digital disc (CD) has 128-bits of sampling.  In pure mathematics, it's the hardware components, such as 256-bit Arithmetic Logic Units (ALU).  There are more sensitive ALUs, such as 1024, but they are more costly (each bit requires an additional bit in the data bus for transferring data).

Comment: If the maximum sensitivity is 8 bits will that suffice?  You can't really ask for "maximum sensitivity", because that depends on the input device and platform.  NVIDIA makes Graphics Processors with 128 cores, 2048 cores and beyond.  What would be the *maximum sensitivity* in this case?

Comment: I mean, the best as i can get with a normal laptop, the full potential, it may be low compared to _real maximum_