# My For Loop condition is not working even when the expression is

Tags: c++, for-loop, visual-c++, integer, c++17

So I am trying to find the number of digits in a given int. The way I opted to find the digits was to divide the given int by powers of 10. Since I would be dividing by integers, the code would eventually reach a 0 when 10 is raised to a high enough power. There would be a tracker that tracks every iteration of this and that tracker would be able to tell me how digits there were.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

int findDigits(int x)
{
    //tracks the digits of int
    int power{ 0 };

    for (int i = 0; x / pow(10, i) != 0; i++) //the condition is not working as it should
    {
        //I checked the math expression and it is getting the intended result of zero at i = 3
        int quotient = x / pow(10, i);

        //I then checked the condition and it is becoming false when the expression results in 0
        bool doesWork;
        if (x / pow(10, i) != 0)
            doesWork = true;
        else
            doesWork = false;

        power = i;
    }

    return power;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "157 has " << findDigits(157) << " digits";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Much simpler: keep dividing by 10 until the result is 0.

Comment: So what is the problem? Please describe it (including expected and actual output).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you are NOT dividing it by integer. [pow() returns double](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/pow/) according to the c++ reference. Therefore, the result of x / pow(10, i) would be double. ruining everything.

There is two option:

1. Use `x / (int)pow(10, i) != 0` within the for loop condition. And PLUS 1 to the result.
   But be aware, [floating result of pow() might be corrupted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9704195/why-pow10-5-9-999-in-c).
   If you **don't** have *decent reason* to use `pow()`, stick to the second option.
2. Go with below for loop instead.

```cpp
for (; x != 0; x /= 10) {
  power++;
}
```

It divides original number *x* by 10 until it reaches 0.

Comment: The 1st option is not safe. What if `pow(10, 1)` returns `9.99` for example?

Comment: It's not a question of casting, in fact, `dynamic_cast` is just completely unnecessary. The problem is that floating point math is [broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: oh I see, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9704195/why-pow10-5-9-999-in-c) might cause problem. I'll edit my answer. Thx for the notice @cigien.

Comment: Broken by design, mind you. That break is what allows huge numbers.

Comment: Another trick is there aren't many powers of 10 you can fit in an integer. You can make a small array and use `i` as the index into the array. No math. No loops.