# Wrong answer in Codechef

Tags: c++, windows, c++17

This https://www.codechef.com/CCRR2021/problems/CCRR002 is the codechef contest question. I can't figure out that what's wrong with my C++ code

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int T;
    cin>>T;
    while(T--){
        int l;
        cin>>l;
        for(int i=pow(10,l-1);i<pow(10,l);i++)
        {
            if(i%10!=0)
                cout<<i<<endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

> Raashi was given a task to a crack password. Given a length ‘l′,
> Raashi wants to try all passwords of length ‘l′. Help her to find all
> possible passwords of length ‘l′ using recursion. Digits of the
> password are from 1 to 9.
>
> Input: First line contains integer ‘t’, denoting number of testcases.
> For each testcase: There is one integer ‘l’. Output: For each testcase
> print all the possible passwords separated by new line.
>
> Constraints 1≤t≤6 1≤l≤6
>
> Sample Input:
> 1
> 2
>
> Sample Output:
> 11
> 12
> 13
> 14
> 15
> 16
> 17
> 18
> 19
> 21
> 22
> 23
> 24
> 25
> 26
> 27
> 28
> 29
> 31
> 32
> 33
> 34
> 35
> 36
> 37
> 38
> 39
> 41
> 42
> 43
> 44
> 45
> 46
> 47
> 48
> 49
> 51
> 52
> 53
> 54
> 55
> 56
> 57
> 58
> 59
> 61
> 62
> 63
> 64
> 65
> 66
> 67
> 68
> 69
> 71
> 72
> 73
> 74
> 75
> 76
> 77
> 78
> 79
> 81
> 82
> 83
> 84
> 85
> 86
> 87
> 88
> 89
> 91
> 92
> 93
> 94
> 95
> 96
> 97
> 98
> 99

Comment: I should write a paper, `pow() function considered harmful`

Comment: You forgot to exclude passwords like `101` for example, for `l=3`

Answer (score 2):

`pow` is dangerous because it's heavily optimized to return an approximation as a floating point value. It might return `9999.9999999` on certain systems when your invoke `pow(10,5)`, even though you expected it to return `10000.0`.  That issue is heavily discussed here: [Why pow(10,5) = 9,999 in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9704195/why-pow10-5-9-999-in-c)

Back to the original coding question.  The question on that coding challenge site specifically calls for **recursion**.  To make it happy and without using any math libraries:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void enumerate(const string& prefix, int length)
{
    if (length <= 0)
    {
        cout << prefix << endl;
        return;
    }

    for (char c = '1'; c <= '9'; c++)
    {
        string s = prefix + c;
        enumerate(s, length - 1);
    }
}


int main()
{
    int testCaseCount, length;

    cin >> testCaseCount;
    for (int i = 0; i < testCaseCount; i++)
    {
        cin >> length;
        enumerate("", length);
    }
    return 0;
}
```