# Unexpected behavior when using strncpy

Tags: c, string

I am working on a problem that required computing a long sequence of numbers by concatenating consecutive integer numbers. I manage to build a sequence of 1 million digits (K=6) but the program become not functional when I try to build a sequence of 10 million digits(K=7).

I tried putting using a debugger but didn't got much insight from it.
code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
// no segfault occurs for K<=6
#define K 7

int main() {
    char s[(int)pow(10, K) + 2];
    char *ptr_s = s;
    char *end = &s[(int)pow(10, K)];

    for (int i = 1;; i++) {
        char buf[K+2];
        snprintf(buf, K+1, "%d", i); // problemetic line
        if (ptr_s >= end) {
            break;
        }
        int len = strlen(buf);
        if (ptr_s + len > end) {
            len = end - ptr_s;
        }
        strncpy(ptr_s, buf, len);
        ptr_s += len;
    }

    int answer = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i <= K; i++) {
        answer *= s[(int)pow(10, i)-1] - '0';
    }
    printf("%d\n", answer);

    return 0;
}
```

debugger info:

```
(gdb) break 1
Breakpoint 1 at 0x401090: file euler.c, line 7.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/runner/CCC/euler 
warning: Error disabling address space randomization: Operation not permitted
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/nix/store/4nlgxhb09sdr51nc9hdm8az5b08vzkgx-glibc-2.35-163/lib/libthread_db.so.1".

Breakpoint 1, main () at euler.c:7
7   int main() {
(gdb) next
14          snprintf(buf, K+1, "%d", i);
(gdb) next
8       char s[(int)pow(10, K) + 2];
(gdb) next
12      for (int i = 1;; i++) {
(gdb) next
14          snprintf(buf, K+1, "%d", i);
(gdb) next

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000401127 in snprintf (__fmt=0x402004 "%d", __n=8, __s=0x7ffc0a7a431f "") at /nix/store/4pqv2mwdn88h7xvsm7a5zplrd8sxzvw0-glibc-2.35-163-dev/include/bits/stdio2.h:54
54    return __builtin___snprintf_chk (__s, __n, __USE_FORTIFY_LEVEL - 1,
```

Comment: 10 million bytes is about 10Mb, and it is allocated on the stack, which is probably smaller than that on your system.

Comment: Time for `malloc()`.

Comment: Aside, consider using powers of 2 instead of 10, so you could replace this `pow` call with a simple bit-shift (you will need a wide enough integer type though...)

Comment: Aside: after using `strncpy()` you should always write a nul terminator into the last element of the array. It's a well documented weakness of the function that this is not guaranteed. unlike `snprintf()`.

Comment: `strncpy()` is one of those functions like `gets()` that should never have been added to the standard. It doesn't do what people naively expect it to from the name.

Comment: OT: Please don't use the floating-point `pow` function for integer powers.

Comment: The 3rd parameter of strncpy should be the size of the destination, not the source. Since you aren't using it to prevent buffer overflow, just use strcpy.

Comment: Note well that this: `char s[(int)pow(10, K) + 2];` declares a *variable-length* array, not an ordinary array, notwithstanding that there are no *bona fide* variables in the size expression.  Aside from the problem of its size, there is at least one C implementation in wide use that does not accept VLAs.

Comment: @EugeneSh. *10 million bytes is about 10Mb...*  [It could only be 10,000,001 bytes and not 10,000,002 bytes...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9704195/why-pow10-5-9-999-in-c)

Comment: @Shawn AIUI, it was added for the benefit of the original Unix filesystem. It had a 14-character field for filenames, and if a filename was the max length it didn't have a null terminator.

Comment: @Barmar Should have stayed as an internal kernel function, not escaped into the wild.

Comment: @Shawn Those were the days before `readdir()`. Applications opened the directory file and read it directly into a struct.

Comment: @JohnBollinger. No it is not if you use any modern compiler as K is constant expression. `pow` will not be called It is "normal" array

Comment: Yes it is, @gulpr.  How the compiler handles `pow()` in practice is irrelevant.  An expression involving a call to `pow()` does not satisfy the definition of an integer constant expression, regardless of when the value is actually computed, and an array any of whose dimensions is given by an expression that is not an integer constant expression is a VLA.  Refer to, for example, C17 paragraphs 6.6/6 and 6.7.6.2/4.

Comment: thanks guys. i found how to more efficiently take integer power from this article:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101439/the-most-efficient-way-to-implement-an-integer-based-power-function-powint-int. also using char *s=malloc(...) works. but i am curious why the traceback would say snprintf causes the coredump? is it because the stack is all taken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For memory error, you can use [valgrind](https://valgrind.org/).

That what `valgrind` output tell you :

```
➜ RTFM valgrind ./a.out
==15553== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==15553== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL d, by Julian Seward et al.
==15553== Using Valgrind-3.18.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==15553== Command: ./a.out
==15553==
==15553== Stack overflow in thread #1: can't grow stack to 0x1ffe801000
==15553==
==15553== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==15553==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x1FFE802A58
==15553== Stack overflow in thread #1: can't grow stack to 0x1ffe801000
==15553==    at 0x109251: main (in /home/RTFM/tmp/a.out)
==15553==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==15553==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==15553==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==15553==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==15553==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==15553==
==15553== HEAP SUMMARY:
==15553==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==15553==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==15553==
==15553== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==15553==
==15553== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==15553== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
[1]    15553 segmentation fault  valgrind ./a.out
```

As you can see, that the result of a Stack overflow.

System alloc stack with a fix size, here valgrind tell use the stack size for this run is `8388608`.

That where you want to use the heap with malloc to allocate your memory :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // for malloc
#define K 7

int main() {
    char *s;
    char *ptr_s;
    char *end;

    s = malloc(sizeof(char) * ((int)pow(10, K) + 2)); // now we use malloc
    if (s == NULL) //check if malloc() call fail
        return (1); // if fail return error code in main()
    ptr_s = s; // set s ptr
    end = s + (int)pow(10, K); // set s end_ptr
    
    ... // your code here

    free(s); // don't forget to free memory after
    return 0;
}
```

You can also, use `static` or a `global` variable.
Because they are created in [.bss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.bss)/[.data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment) and not on stack, you have more memory, but that really bad code and you should using heap.