# Subtracting close together numbers in php

Tags: php, floating-point, floating-accuracy, floating-point-exceptions

Why does

`<?php echo 194.95-194.94; ?>`

output

```
0.0099999999999909
```

What am i missing here? This is php 5.2.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The accuracy of PHP float calculate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957705/the-accuracy-of-php-float-calculate)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue is that you cannot represent 0.01 exactly in floating point.

Have a look at [what every programmer should know about floating point](http://floating-point-gui.de/) for a great explanation of why this is, and what to do about it.

Answer (score 3):

While Mark's answer is okay, it may still leave you wondering why you got the answer you did.  For example, try

```
<?php echo 0.01; ?>
```

PHP happily prints `0.01`.

In your case `194.95` and `194.94` were both stored in as-close-a-binary-form as could be accommodated in IEEE 754, and their difference was too far away from the basic `0.01` that *could* be rendered "properly".

Try out your example on an online calcuator such as http://babbage.cs.qc.edu/IEEE-754/Decimal.html.  Should be interesting.