# why 0.1+0.2-0.3= 5.5511151231258E-17 in php

Tags: php, floating-point, precision

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The accuracy of PHP float calculate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957705/the-accuracy-of-php-float-calculate)

when i executed the code below in eclipse , the result was not 0 but 5.5511151231258E-17

```
$a = 0.1+0.2-0.3;
echo $a;
```

could someone tell me why?

Comment: You do know that 5.5511151231258E-17 means 0.000000000000000055511151231258, right? Just in case you are wondering about the notation...

Comment: echo round($a,15); should work for your purpose

Answer (score 7):

This is because **floating point numbers have limited precision**.

You can find more information about this trait on [this page in the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php).

> Floating point numbers have limited precision. Although it depends on
>   the system, PHP typically uses the IEEE 754 double precision format,
>   which will give a maximum relative error due to rounding in the order
>   of 1.11e-16. Non elementary arithmetic operations may give larger
>   errors, and, of course, error progragation must be considered when
>   several operations are compounded.
>
> Additionally, rational numbers that are exactly representable as
>   floating point numbers in base 10, like 0.1 or 0.7, do not have an
>   exact representation as floating point numbers in base 2, which is
>   used internally, no matter the size of the mantissa. Hence, they
>   cannot be converted into their internal binary counterparts without a
>   small loss of precision. This can lead to confusing results: for
>   example, floor((0.1+0.7)*10) will usually return 7 instead of the
>   expected 8, since the internal representation will be something like
>   7.9999999999999991118....
>
> So never trust floating number results to the last digit, and never
>   compare floating point numbers for equality. If higher precision is
>   necessary, the arbitrary precision math functions and gmp functions
>   are available.

Please note that this is not a trait specific to PHP; [it is just the way floating point numbers work](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems).

Answer (score 1):

You're running into PHP's [floating point precision issues](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php). All languages have them, you've just found PHP's.

Answer (score 1):

This is not PHP specific, as others have mentioned. However, you can avoid limited floating point precision by using round():

```
<?php
$a = 0.1+0.3-0.2;
echo round($a, 2);
?>
```

Of course you will need to know the number of digits beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

It's because computers can't accurately represent floating point numbers. This isn't specific to PHP.

See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems) for details.