# precision of Double and Decimal (in .NET)

Tags: .net, floating-point, decimal, precision, floating-accuracy

As far as I understand now, Decimal is 2 times bigger than Double (128 bits vs 64 bits). So it can represent numbers with bigger precision. But it also uses numeric system with base 10, instead of binary. Maybe the last trait of Decimal affects the following results?

```
Microsoft (R) F# Interactive version 11.0.60610.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved.

For help type #help;;

> let x = 1.0m / 3.0m ;;
val x : decimal = 0.3333333333333333333333333333M

> x * 3.0m ;;
val it : decimal = 0.9999999999999999999999999999M

> let y = 1.0 / 3.0 ;;
val y : float = 0.3333333333

> y * 3.0 ;;
val it : float = 1.0

> it = 1.0 ;;
val it : bool = true
```

As you can see, Double prints as 1.0 again after division and multiplication by 3.0. I tried different divisors, and the situation is the same.
(note for ones who don't know F# - `float` is basically synonym for `double` in F#)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between Decimal, Float and Double in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/618535/what-is-the-difference-between-decimal-float-and-double-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nice thing about the type `decimal` when displayed with our usual decimal notation is that it is WYSIWYG: printing enough decimal digits (and `0.3333333333333333333333333333M` certainly looks like enough), you can see the exact number the machine is working with. There is no surprise that three times that makes `0.9999999999999999999999999999M`: you can do it with pen and paper and reproduce the result(2).

In binary, it would require many more decimal digits to see the exact number being represented, and they are usually not all printed (but the situation would be just as simple it they were). It is only a coincidence that in this case the binary multiplication of `3.0` by `1.0 / 3.0` makes `1.0`. The property [holds for some numbers but does not have to hold for all numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18031221/rounding-oddity-what-is-special-about-100/18036308#18036308). In fact, the result may not be 1.0, and your language may be printing fewer decimal digits than would reveal this. An exponential form 1.DD…DDEXXX with 16 digits after the dot suffices to distinguish all double-precision numbers, although it does not show the exact value of the number.

So, in summary:

- decimal is WYSIWYG, you got 0.99… because you multiplied 0.33… by 3
- the result in binary may not be 1.0, but only print as such with the default limited number of decimals for binary numbers in your language
- even if it is 1.0, that's a coincidence that might not have happened with another number instead of 3.0.

### Miscellaneous notes

1. If F# is like OCaml in this respect, you can print enough decimals to distinguish 1.0 from another `float` with `Printf.printf "%.16e"`.
2. F#'s `decimal` type is WYSIWYG but you have to remember that some numbers have 28 digits of precision and most have 29. See supercat's answer or the comments below for details.
3. The hexadecimal notation has the same WYSIWYG property for binary floating-point as the decimal notation has for `decimal`.
   C99, of all languages and years, has the best support for fine floating-point manipulation, and it supports hexadecimal for input and output.

An example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  double d = 1 / 3.0;
  printf("%a\n%a\n", d, 3*d);
}
```

Executing produces:

```
$ gcc -std=c99 t.c && ./a.out 
0x1.5555555555555p-2
0x1p+0
```

With pen and paper, we can multiply `0x1.5555555555555p-2` by `3`. We obtain `0x3.FFFFFFFFFFFFFp-2`, or `0x1.FFFFFFFFFFFFF8p-1` after normalization. This number is not representable exactly as a binary64 floating-point number (it has too many significant digits), and the “nearest” representable number, returned by the multiplication, is `1.0`. (The rule that ties must be rounded to the nearest **even** number is applied. Of the two equally near alternatives `0x1.FFFFFFFFFFFFFp-1` and `1.0`, the `1.0` result is the “even” one.)

Comment: >If F# is like OCaml in this respect, you can print enough decimals to distinguish 1.0 from another float with Printf.printf "%.16e".
   - As you can see in last lines of code, they're actually equal.

Comment: @SargeBorsch So I confirmed later without editing my question, which felt like it should continue to cover the possibility of a non-1.0 value of type `float` printing as `1.0`. But I have edited my answer now with an explicit computation for the binary case.

Comment: I did some tests in Java, and the smallest natural number for which the result of multiplying back is not exactly one is 49.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Following the same sort of reasoning as in the answer I linked, it seems possible to infer some more properties about this: for `n` between 1 and 2^52, `(1. / n) * n` should only ever be approximated down, never up, and only when `(1. / n)` is itself rounded down with respect to the mathematical result. I should now write some tests to check this line of reasoning that I have never been more than half-confident about.

Comment: With `System.Double` (also known as IEEE binary64) we have for example `7.7/3.0 * 3.0` is not `7.7`, and `7.8/3.0 * 3.0` is not `7.8`. It is perhaps more surprising that `System.Decimal` can provide examples like `800m/3m * 3m` and `170m/3m * 3m` where the integer comes back, only with trailing zeroes appended. The first example might be unexpected since `800m` and approx `266.7m` are in the same "decade" (namely `100m` to `1000m`) but is related to the fact that some `System.Decimal` have only 28 digits precision, whereas others (most) have 29. Opposite: `500m/3m * 3m` and `260m/3m * 3m`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen “some System.Decimal have only 28 digits precision, whereas others (most) have 29”: So I gathered from supercat's answer. IEEE 754-2008's decimal floating-point system's decades go from 1 to 10, but it makes sense to use lopsided decades from 0.7923 to 7.923 for a pure software implementation.

Comment: What you quoted me for about .NET's `System.Decimal` is different in the IEEE format decimal128. In .NET `System.Decimal`, the mantissa integer is in the range `0` to `79228162514264337593543950335`. The last number is `2**96 - 1`. So a `System.Decimal` whose leading (most significant) digit is `9` or `8`, or over `7922...` is different from other `System.Decimal`. In IEEE decimal128 the mantissa integer goes from `0` to `9999999999999999999999999999999999` (that's `10**34 - 1`), so that's more "decimal" in a way.

Comment: I would say .NET `System.Decimal` has two types of decades, both `1` to `10` and `0.7922...` to `7.922...` while the IEEE decimal128 has only one type of decade, `1` to `10`, and that is a "natural" decimal decade.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: I wonder if the use of floating-point `Decimal` was an effort at "compromise" among people who couldn't decide what a fixed-point scaling factor should be?  Personally, I consider decimal floating-point a silly idea except in I/O-heavy applications like calculators *which store things in BCD*.  Addition and subtraction, which are the most common operations in accounting applications, are vastly slower than with fixed-point, and cannot offer guarantees like `a+b-a==b` which fixed-point types inherently do.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you are observing in `double` is attributable to the fact that the result of multiplying 1/3 by three has a different scale from 1/3.  The situation would be analogous to what would see if, always keeping exactly three decimal figures, one were to compute 1.00/7.00 (yielding .143) and multiply that result by 7 (the exact value of which would be 1.001, but which gets rounded to 1.00).  Essentially, the division picks up a significant figure (accurate to 0.001 even though the original number was only accurate to 0.01), which allows the multiplication to yield the correct result.

With type `Decimal`, even if `x/y` cannot be stored exactly, the value of `(x/y)*y` (where `1 < y < 10`) will often equal `x` if the multiplication causes a change of scale requiring a rounding step.  The reason that (1D/3D)*3D does not yield 1D is that while `Decimal` values above roughly 7.923 lose a decimal place at the right for each power of ten by which they exceed that quantity, those below 0.7922 do not gain places.  Thus, dividing by 3 a value in the range 7.923 to 23.76 and then multiplying be 3 will yield the original value; likewise if one uses a value 79.23 to 233.76, etc.  Division of a value below 7.923 by any value greater than one is generally not a reversible operation except when the result is an exact multiple of 10^-28.

Comment: There is the opposite situation: 1m / 3m * 3m <> 1m, 1D / 3D * 3D = 1D

Comment: @SargeBorsch: Are you saying that I needed to clarify that the first paragraph was talking about why the result gets correctly rounded when using `double`?