# Someone tells me how the floating number 1.002 * 10 ^3 is represented in the computer?

Tags: floating-point, floating-accuracy

The question is in the title. Say, for a 64-bit machine.

I want to know how the floating number is represented because I would like to know the result of

```
1.002 * 10^3 - 1.000 * 10 ^3
```

in machine representation. Thanks for your ideas.

Comment: The result of the above operation is 2. Are you looking for the `float` representation of 2?

Comment: Result is `2`. As whole numbers with fewer than ~7 (float) or ~16 (double) decimal digits of precision, these can be represented exactly.

Comment: Even with the [half-precision floating-point format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-precision_floating-point_format) it appears that these numbers are exactly representable. But since you say 64-bit machine, do you consider double-precision?

Comment: @barakmanos `1.002E3` is clearly `1002`, but `1.002 * 1E3` might not be, because 1.002 is just about a power of two and 1002 just below. It depends how the expression is interpreted (and see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18031221/rounding-oddity-what-is-special-about-100/18036308#18036308 for a quick study of the result of multiplying an exact floating-point number by an inexact one in order to produce a product that would, if carried mathematically, arrived to a number representable exactly as a floating-point number).

Comment: @barakmanos If `1.002 * 1E3` is not `1002`, then clearly `1.002 * 1E3 - 1000.0` is not 2, since this subtraction is exact.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: Thank you for pointing that out. In any case, regardless of the specific value at hand, a simple C program can reveal the exact representation of any `float` value (as depicted in my answer below).

Comment: Are you looking for the binary (64 bit) representation of a floating point number? That can be found here: kipirvine.com/asm/workbook/floating_tut.htm "1 bit for the sign, 11 bits for the exponent, and 52 bits for the mantissa".

Comment: Since 1.002 * 10^3 is not C, it is not quite clear whether 1.002e3 is meant (which is 1002 and can be stored exactly), or 1.002 * 1e3 (which is not exact, although a clever compiler might notice that 1.002e3 is meant).

Answer (score 2):

If you are you looking for the representation of a `float` value in memory, then you can write down a small C program to reveal the answer. Taking the value specified in your question, for example:

```
float f = (float)(1.002*1000-1.000*1000);
char* p = (char*)&f;
int   i;

// Little Endian
for (i=0; i<sizeof(f); i++)
    printf("%.2X",p[i]);

// Big Endian
for (i=sizeof(f)-1; i>=0; i--)
    printf("%.2X",p[i]);
```

Please note that the `"%.2X"` string is correspondent with `CHAR_BIT` being equal to `8`, and should generally be set as `"%.NX"`, with `N` being equal to `CHAR_BIT/4`.

Comment: The `%a` format specifier gives a slightly more readable representation.

Comment: @tmyklebu: Thanks for the tip (as I wasn't really aware of this particular specifier).

Comment: This answer is wrong as the operation is NOT necessarily 2: 1.002 * 10 ^3 cannot be exactly represented in bits.  See the comments earlier from  Pascal Cuoq.   Therefore, I vote up but do NOT accept this answer. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @zell: The answer tells you how to get the representation of **any** `float` value. In your question, the value is 2 or very close to it, so I used 2 as an example. Since you insist, I changed it to be the precised value specified in your question.