# Rounding error for double?

Tags: java, floating-point, double, floating-point-precision

When I run the following code:

```
double x = 4.35;
double y = x * 100;
System.out.println(y);
```

I get `434.99999999999994` which is expected due to the nature of floating point precision. However when I run:

```
double x = 4.35;
double y = x * 1000;
System.out.println(y);
```

I get `4350.0` in the console. Similarly when I replace the `1000` with `10`, I get `43.5`, which is peculiar, since there is no rounding error for these numbers. It seems that there is only rounding error when I mulptiply the double by `10 to the power of the number of decimal places`. Why is it like that?

Also, when I tried running the three blocks of code using `4.25` as my value for `x`, I got a nice `425.0` in the console. Does rounding error only apply to some decimal values?

**EDIT:** Dividing 4.35 by 10 also gave me a wacky decimal (`0.43499999999999994` to be exact). Also, if I set x to 43.5, there were no rounding errors at all. Multiplying by 10 gave me 435.0.

**EDIT 2:** I think some people are misinterpreting my question. I'm asking **why** this happens and *not* how to avoid running into these errors.

Comment: Interestingly, when I use a `float`, I get 435.0 instead.

Comment: The reason lies in the way the computation is implemented in the particular CPU you are using. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_unit

Comment: A previous question about, as you say, why this happens rather than how to avoid it, and why some values en up exactly the mathematical result, is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18031221/rounding-oddity-what-is-special-about-100/18036308#18036308

Comment: To answer for your specific values, `4.35 * 100.0` was likely to end up different from exactly `435.0` because 435 is just below the power of two 512 and 4.35 just above the power of two 4, whereas 4350 is just above the power of two 4096, making `4.35 * 1000.0` unable to produce anything other than `4350.0`

Comment: PLEASE, PLEASE read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).  It is the canonical answer to this question, which gets asked at least once per day on SO.

Comment: @JimGarrison That document only directly answers this question if one is satisfied with the answer “OMG this is very complicated I'd better treat floating-point error as random”, which is fine as long as one remembers one is making an abstraction. If one is less easily satisfied, then the document you link to only answers the question in the same sense that the Java language definition answers most Java questions on StackOverflow.

Comment: You can see what the exact values are using BigDecimal, this will explain way some values round as expected and some should a small error.

Comment: As @PeterLawrey mentioned, BigDecimal can be very useful in understanding the reasons behind floating point results. I can be used to display the exact values of inputs, the result if it is a decimal fraction, the difference between that exact result and the rounded result, and differences between the exact result and the pair of floating point numbers that bracket it.

Answer (score 1):

The computations which do not produce any rounding error are those that can be represented exactly in the binary system. That includes all integers and, e.g, 0.5 decimal which is 0.1 binary or 0.25 decimal which is 0.01 binary. Hence the example you posted has no rounding error. 0.35 decimal however cannot be represented with finitely many binary digits.

Comment: 4.35 is not represented exactly in binary.

Comment: True. Added that to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to avoid floating point arithmetic errors. The number of bits used in representing a number will always be finite. All you can do is to use data types with higher precision (bits) like 
 [java.math.BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html). Read [The need for BigDecimal](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/the_need_for_bigdecimal) by John Zukowski for more information.
Try this::

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

double x = 4.35;
BigDecimal bd1 = BigDecimal.valueOf(x);
BigDecimal bd2= BigDecimal.valueOf(100);
BigDecimal multiply = bd1.multiply(bd2);
System.out.println(multiply);
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems