# Multiplying by 100

Tags: ruby, floating-point

Can someone explain to me why:

```
33.8 * 100 # => 3379.999999999995
```

but

```
23.8 * 100 # => 2380.0
```

Comment: You can no more represent 0.1 exactly in binary than you can 1/3 in decimal: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: The question is not clear. Do you mean "why the answers are different"? It is because `33.8` and `23.8` are different.

Comment: @duffymo - but both 33.8 and 23.8 contain "0.1", yet 23.8*100 returns the "expected" value. Why?

Comment: Read the article.  This is how floating point numbers work in IEEE.

Comment: Although your question is about the other factor, it is more accurately a duplicate of this question than of the one that was chosen, and my answer provides some elements to explain why one constant gets rounded back to an integral value and the other doesn't: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18036308/139746

Answer (score 4):

Floating-point numbers cannot precisely represent all real numbers, and floating-point operations cannot precisely represent true arithmetic operations, this leads to many surprising situations.

I advise to read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems

You may want to use [BigDecimal](http://ruby-doc.org//stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html) to avoid such problems.

Comment: BigDecimal won't represent 1/3 exactly.  No help there.

Comment: It would return the right numbers for the examples in the question.

Comment: spickerman - Thanks for your quick answer. A couple more questions:If floating-point numbers are so inaccurate for simple arithmetic operations, what's the point of the Float class? Also, is there a way to predict which floating numbers would be "inaccurate" and which would return the expected result, as 23.8*100 did?

Comment: @Doctore: Floats are way faster and need less memory than BigDecimal, and very often you don't need the exact precision.