# floated do-while index says: 0.8 < 0.8

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The accuracy of PHP float calculate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957705/the-accuracy-of-php-float-calculate)

```
<?php
    $foo = 0;
    do {
        echo "\$foo = $foo".($foo >= 0.8 ? " >= 0.8<br>\n" : " < 0.8<br>\n");
        $foo = $foo + 0.1;
    } while($foo <= 1);
?>
```

leads to the following output:

```
$foo = 0 < 0.8
$foo = 0.1 < 0.8
$foo = 0.2 < 0.8
$foo = 0.3 < 0.8
$foo = 0.4 < 0.8
$foo = 0.5 < 0.8
$foo = 0.6 < 0.8
$foo = 0.7 < 0.8
$foo = 0.8 < 0.8
$foo = 0.9 >= 0.8
$foo = 1 >= 0.8
```

.. even var_dump does not tell me more then it's 0.8. Scary:

```
round($foo,1) >= 0.8
```

solves the problem - help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To supplement the other answers:

```
<?php
$foo = 0;

do {
    echo sprintf('%.16f %s 0.8', $foo, $foo >= 0.8 ? '>=' : '<') . PHP_EOL;
    $foo = $foo + 0.1;
} while($foo <= 1);
```

produces

```
0.0000000000000000 < 0.8
0.1000000000000000 < 0.8
0.2000000000000000 < 0.8
0.3000000000000000 < 0.8
0.4000000000000000 < 0.8
0.5000000000000000 < 0.8
0.6000000000000000 < 0.8
0.7000000000000000 < 0.8
0.7999999999999999 < 0.8
0.8999999999999999 >= 0.8
0.9999999999999999 >= 0.8
```

http://ideone.com/ggbMl

Go figure ;)

---

You could use round, depending on your case. But the typical solution is using the so called [machine epsilon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon). Your condition then would be

```
define ('EPS', 1e-15);
if (abs($foo - 0.8) < EPS) {
  // ...
```

The value of your EPS depends obviously on your platform but the value used in the condition also depends on the number of arithmetic operations you did on the number as each operation causes more rounding error. For more information read through the wiki article.

Comment: thanks a lot for this tiny lesson ;)

Comment: +1 for a more complete answer (thought about this, too, but as I'm not familiar with PHP, I might have missed something or given bad advice)

Comment: One more thing that might make this case more obvious - try running `printf('%.30f', 0.1);`

Answer (score 3):

Another [floating point accuracy problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems). What you think is 0.8 isn't exactly 0.8 to the computer (although he might even output 0.8).

Answer (score 2):

Just standard floating-point rounding issues.

The typical float-to-string conversions throw away the least significant binary digits, so two numbers that appear as `0.8` aren't necessarily the same. And since `0.8` isn't representable using binary floating-points, neither of them is exactly `0.8`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you cannot exactly represent 0.8 in binary floating-point.  You cannot exactly represent 0.1, either.  So using in an inexact value of 0.1 to calculate 0.8 will be unlikely to match an inexact value of 0.8.

Comment: I don not understand much about the mechanics down the road yet. Is there any way to make such case work with decimals without usage of round()?

Comment: @Sascha Schulz, see the end of my answer.

Comment: @hakre IMO mentioning duplicate questions should be posted as a comment, and not edited into somebody else's answer.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Please read the FAQ, especially the section about ownership.

Comment: Even without ownership issues, I believe that this should be a comment.