# PHP unexpected integer/float calculation

Tags: php

```
<?php
echo (int) ((0.1 + 0.7) * 10);
```

Why does this output `7` instead of expected `8` ?

Comment: As per a few million OTHER questions, 0.1 + 0.7 is actually 0.7999999999999 internally.

Comment: And `(int)` discards the decimal part, not rounds to the nearest integer.

Comment: [Clicky](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Machine_precision_and_backward_error_analysis). Very common :)

Comment: Drop the `(int)` and you should see the expected.

Comment: See also: [The accuracy of PHP float calculate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957705/the-accuracy-of-php-float-calculate)

Comment: Considering this exact example and explanation can be found in the manual...... http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php  http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php#warn.float-precision

Answer (score 2):

From the  [PHP manual](http://php.net/language.types.float):

> ... This can lead to confusing results: for example, `floor((0.1+0.7)*10)` will usually return `7` instead of the expected `8`, since the internal representation will be something like `7.9999999999999991118....`

It's much recommended to use the [`bcmath`](http://php.net/bcmath) functions if you want accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments. `0.1 + 0.7` is not actually `0.8` it is stored as something like `0.79999999`. When you cast it to an `int`, it will truncate the decimal and just output 7. If you don't cast it to an `int` it wont truncate and output the expected value.

```
echo (0.1 + 0.7);
echo ((0.1 + 0.7) * 10);
echo (int) ((0.1 + 0.7) * 10);
```

Output:

```
0.8
8
7
```

Note the very large warning on floating point numbers in the [PHP Guide](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php). It pretty much is the exact example you are asking about.

Comment: However if they want an `int` and the value is `(0.09 + .7)* 10` that will just rely on php's internal precision. Presumably an integer is the desired output...?

Comment: I think the question is *why* not how do I do this..

Comment: I suppose so, since it is copied from the php documentation.

Answer (score 0):

To get past the `int` truncation problem, use `round()`, with specified precision

```
 echo round(0.09+0.7,1)*10;
 8
```

This will give you an integer, unlike just omitting the `round()` or `int()` in the case of

```
echo (0.09+0.7)*10;
7.9
```