# PHP eval give wrong result

Tags: php, eval

Something is wrong with `eval` function

```
$string = '$val = 1526.65 - 1519.99;';
eval($string);
echo $val; => give 6.6600000000001, expected 6.66
```

The test is here : http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fa5b2e7e6602e60cdeb054b705a69e4a226bd52c

Anyone have an explanation ?

Answer (score 5):

This has nothing to do with `eval`, since the same result is produced by running that line normally. The reason for the strange result is [floating point error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples).

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to flag the question as a duplicate if the other question provides answers to this one?

Comment: Do you have suggestion to bypass this error? Because I need to do correct calculation here...

Comment: @Anonymous Yeah, sorry

Comment: @ThanhTrung See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957705/the-accuracy-of-php-float-calculate for a couple PHP-specific suggestions.